# Atualizar linha do console com C#

Tags: c#, console

Já fiz esta mesma pergunta uma vez, mas naquele caso eu precisava para a linguagem python, agora preciso resolver este mesmo problema, com a linguagem C#

Tenho um loop em **C#**, e gostaria de informar o valor de uma variável a cada vez que ela é atualizada, porém **não quero sujar o console** dando print toda vez e **nem limpar todo o console**.

Existe uma maneira de eu obter este resultado?

```
int a = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Executando processo:");
while (True) {
    a = a +1
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

**O resultado ao final de 3 interações é:**

Interação 1:

```
$ - Executando processo: 
$ - 1
```

Interação 2:

```
$ - Executando processo:
$ - 1 
$ - 2
```

Interação 3:

```
$ - Executando processo:
$ - 1 
$ - 2
$ - 3
```

**E gostaria de obter o seguinte resultado:**

Interação 1:

```
$ - Executando processo:
$ - 1
```

Interação 2:

```
$ - Executando processo:
$ - 2
```

Interação 3:

```
$ - Executando processo:
$ - 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `Console.Write` que imprime na mesma linha.
Fiz uso do *SetCursorPosition* que define a posição do cursor na tela.

```
a = a + 1;
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
Console.Write("{0}", a);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Ótimo, com a versão que você colocou antes, com o "\r", resolveu muito bem o meu problema, só ainda não consegui entender bem como funciona esse caractere de escape.

O Console.SetCursorPosition também funcionou

Comment: o \r corresponde a um retorno do cursor